# Problem with reduce function angular code

Tags: angular

i have this code

```
let groupedByTypeResult: any[] = this.lastFour.reduce(function(
          obj: any,
          item: any
        ) {
          let type = item.type;

          obj[type] = obj[type] || { label: item.type, data: [] };
          obj[type].data.push(item.total);

          return obj;
        },
        {});
```

this code  Group Last Four by Type but i don't want to group it , my data is somethig like that

```
[
    {
        "date": "2021-09-07T00:00:00",
        "type": "type6",
        "total": 744
    },
    {
        "date": "2021-09-07T00:00:00",
        "type": "type5",
        "total": 4769
    },
    {
        "date": "2021-09-08T00:00:00",
        "type": "type4",
        "total": 740
    },
    {
        "date": "2021-09-08T00:00:00",
        "type": "type3",
        "total": 4743
    },
    {
        "date": "2021-09-09T00:00:00",
        "type": "Type2",
        "total": 736
    },
    {
        "date": "2021-09-09T00:00:00",
        "type": "type1",
        "total": 4714
    },
]
```

how can I change that code and have the same type of return (I'm trying to create a bar chart that shows the distribution of types by date and total )

Comment: what is your initial data, what is the expected result?

Comment: my initial data is that json and I want to create a chart that shows the type distribution by date

Comment: It doesnt work that way, share what you attempted, where your getting stuck, share a stackblitz with the issue and the expected result!, then only solution will be found!